# iOS 13 WKWebView not showing pdf file anymore

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview, ios13

I am using `WKWebView` to show a `pdf` file from a remote url. It was working fine in `iOS 12` but in `iOS 13` it just shows blank screen. 
I hit same domain with an image url and that worked fine but it has some issues with `pdf` files only.

```
let myURL = URL(string:"somefileurl.pdf") // If I hit this url in safari, It will download a pdf file.
let myRequest = URLRequest(url: myURL!)
webViewPdf.load(myRequest)
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I figured out that the response' **content-type** was **"application/octet-stream"** instead of **"application/pdf"**

So I load the `WKWebView` as:

```
if let myURL = URL(string:"somefileurl.pdf") {
    if let data = try? Data(contentsOf: myURL) {
       webViewPdf.load(data, mimeType: "application/pdf", characterEncodingName: "", baseURL: myURL)
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm having the opposite issue. I built my app using the iOS 13 SDK but only see the blank screen with PDFs when running it on iOS 12.4.1. Do you have any more insight as to what is different and if this could possibly be changed externally (the download headers, maybe?). I don't want to upload a new build if I can avoid it

Comment: @MattLong if it's a local file, you need to use [`loadFileURL(_:allowingReadAccessTo:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkwebview/1414973-loadfileurl). Put the same file url into both parameters. Boom. Works in iOS 12 and 13.

Comment: @MattLong did you get the resolution, I'm getting the same issue.

Comment: @Deepak I used  fl034 's solution with loadFileURL(_:allowingReadAccessTo:), (albeit I put that into place several months ago)

Comment: @fl034 - great suggestion, now this supports iOS 12, 13 and 14

Answer (score 0):

UIWebView also has the same problem. Fixed as follow(objective-c):

```
[self.webView loadData:data MIMEType:@"application/pdf" textEncodingName:@"" baseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"FilePathOrUrlString"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Just Implement the decidePolicyFor method available in WKNavigationDelegate as given below,

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Void) {
   decisionHandler(.allow)
}
```

and set the delegate in your web view as given below,

```
yourWebView.navigationDelegate = self
```

Answer (score -1):

**For PDF Try This in My Case Working 100%**

```
func openFile(url:URL){
self.displayDocument(filePath: url, type: "pdf")
}



 extension Your ViewControler Name :UIDocumentInteractionControllerDelegate{

            public func documentInteractionControllerViewControllerForPreview(_ controller: UIDocumentInteractionController) -> UIViewController {
                UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.blue
                return self
            }

            public func documentInteractionControllerDidEndPreview(_ controller: UIDocumentInteractionController) {
                UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.clear
                self.documentInteractionController = nil
            }
            func documentInteractionControllerDidDismissOptionsMenu(_ controller: UIDocumentInteractionController) {
                UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.clear
                self.navigationController?.dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)
            }

            func displayDocument(filePath:URL,type:String){
                SVProgressHUD.dismiss()

                self.documentInteractionController = UIDocumentInteractionController(url:filePath )
                // Preview PDF
                self.documentInteractionController.delegate = self
                self.documentInteractionController.presentPreview(animated: true)
            }
        }
```

Comment: What does this have to do with viewing a remote PDF in a WKWebView?

Comment: this code is useful for open PDF in  default document controller. so don't require WKWebView

Comment: But the question is about loading a remote PDF (not local) in a web view.

Comment: its useful For Remote PDF Also you have to pass PDF URL. and PDF is OPEN

Comment: @Amul4608 Question is not about opening a PDF in remote or local. Its about opening a PDF inside a `WKWebView`.

Comment: Did any found the solution ? PDF doesn't load on WKWebView on iOS 13