# Error Domain=WebKitErrorDomain Code=102 "Frame load interrupted"

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

Getting an error while showing pdf in WebView

"Error Domain=WebKitErrorDomain Code=102 "Frame load interrupted"

But with the same code image is populating correctly.

Comment: Facing same issue.

Comment: Can you post the URL you are trying to load?

Comment: I can share the format but cant disclose the full url , Here it is

HOST/api/worklife/upload-files/download?filetoken=tnjGv78shDBtdIl50hepzigMv

Comment: Please check this with real device if it's happening there as well

Comment: Yes i checked it on different devices and with UIWebview and WKWebview as well, but nothing worked for me , When i opened this url on Desktop Browser it directly downloads the file.

Comment: @Arjunhastir Have you tried to add mime type while loading?

Comment: @RajSharma As u see in the above mentioned URL i dont know the extension of the file , So i dont know the MIME type ... only i have the file token

Comment: @Arjunhastir I have a POST request to the server which responds with the PDF data. The fileName with .pdf extension is sent as parameter in application/x-www-form-urlencoded format. I'm getting Error Domain=WebKitErrorDomain Code=102 “Frame load interrupted” error as well. How to solve it? Please help. TIA

Answer (score 5):

Thanks for contributing :)

Finally after spending hours on this , Here i found the solution for this common Webview **"frame load interrupted"** issue:

- Download the file in bytes form
- Store it in the Local Storage
- Load the file in Web view with the local path and it works

Try the below code for the above steps

//Method to Show Document In Web View

```
    func methodToShowDocumentInWebView(strUrl : String, fileName :  String, controller: UIViewController)  {

 //Get Request to download in bytes
       Service.shared()?.callAPI(withURLWithoutHandlingAndLoaderAndHttpStatusCode: strUrl, andLoaderenabled: true, method: "GET", parameters: [:], withController: self, completion: { (data, error, code) in

          if  let dataFile = data {

             let (success , payslipPath) = self.methodToWriteFileLocally(data: dataFile as! Data, fileName: fileName, directory: "Leave")
             if success {
                webviewInstance.loadRequest(NSURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: payslipPath)!))
             }else{
                //Handle Error case
             }
          }
       })
    }
```

//Method to Store data Locally

```
func methodToWriteFileLocally(data : Data, fileName: String, directory : String) -> (success :Bool ,path :URL?) {

   let documentsURL = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first
   let fileURL = documentsURL?.appendingPathComponent(directory)
   let payslipPath = fileURL?.appendingPathComponent(fileName)

   if !FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: payslipPath!.path) {
      do{
         try FileManager.default.createDirectory(atPath: fileURL!.path, withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil)
      }
      catch{
         //Handle Catch
         return (false, nil)

      }
      let writeSuccess =  (data as AnyObject).write(to: payslipPath!, atomically: true)
      return (writeSuccess, payslipPath!)
   }
   else
   {
      let writeSuccess =  (data as AnyObject).write(to: payslipPath!, atomically: true)
      return (writeSuccess, payslipPath!)

   }
}
```

Comment: I have a POST request to the server which responds with the PDF data. The fileName with .pdf extension is sent as parameter in `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` format. I'm getting Error Domain=WebKitErrorDomain Code=102 “Frame load interrupted” error as well. How to solve it? Please help. TIA

Comment: @VaibhavJhaveri did you find the solution ??

Comment: Instead you can use Data(contentsOf: url) to get the bytes and then webView.load(data, mimeType: "application/pdf", characterEncodingName: "utf-8", baseURL: url) adjusting parameters to your case.

Answer (score 0):

The root cause is about **Content-Type**.

This request get a response with
`Content-Type: binary/octet-stream`.

There are many ways to modify the Content-Type to right form
`Content-Type: application/pdf`

Then WKWebView will behave normally.

[This anwser](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58075540/4553503) provides a local solution.